# Proof of radius of convergence exponential function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Suppose one is trying to find the radius of convergence of 
$$ \exp(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} $$

This "proof" was given in the lecture:
$$ \begin{align} r =& \frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt
[n]{|a_n|}} \\ =& \frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt
[n]{\frac{1}{n!}}} \\
=&\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt
[n]{n!}\\
r=& \infty
\end{align}$$

**Other proofs involving the ratio test also seem to inspect the convergence of $\frac{1}{k!}$ instead of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$. Why is one allowed to substitute $\frac{1}{k!}$?**

Comment: For Ratio Test,  $a_{n+1}/a_n = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\dfrac{n!}{x^n} = x/n$.

Comment: The "$x^n$" - terms do not occur, if we look at the $a_n$'s. So we simply have $a_n=\frac{1}{n!}$ here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges if

$$\limsup_{n}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|}=|x|\limsup_{n}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|}<1$$

This is tantamount to the condition

$$|x|<\frac{1}{\limsup_{n}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|}}$$

Since $\limsup_{n}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|}=0$, then $\frac{1}{\limsup_{n}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{n!}\right|}}=\infty$ and the series converges for all $x$.

Comment: To the point, the expression on the right side of the inequality is an expression for the radius of convergence

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for adding this comment.

Answer (score 1):

You consider the following $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left| \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}\frac{k!}{x^k} \right| = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left|\frac{x}{k+1}\right| = |x|\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k+1} = 0$$ as $\frac{1}{k+1}>0$ for $k\geq 1$. So the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and the interval of convergence is $\mathbb{R}$.

Maybe they misspelled something, and in the ratio test they wrote $\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$ In general anyway you want to show that the limit of the coefficients goes to zero, so that the whole limit goes to $0$ and has no dependence on $x$. So probably they just analysed the coefficients for that reason, as they already knew the answer.