# Proof $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$ using the exponential series.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I am trying to proof that
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = 0$$

using the exponential series
$$E(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$

I am aware that I can accomplish the proof using the Taylor series, AM/GM and other methods but I am looking for an approach that focuses on the exponential series.

However, I am struggling to do so, as I not sure what the connection between the series and sequence would be.
The only thing I can think of is that, as a consequence of the series converging, I know that
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = 0$$

but I don't know if that is the right track and how I would precede from there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Recall the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius) of the exponential series ... or check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054653/proof-of-radius-of-convergence-exponential-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\gt 0$ the series converges, so by the root test we have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^n}{n!}}=  x\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \le 1 $$

Since $x$ can be arbitrarily large, the $\limsup$ must be zero, which implies the limit is also zero.

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally makes sense and is actually quite simple, I wonder why I didn't think of that...

Comment: Small improvent: Technically it should be $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left\lvert\frac{x^n}{n!}\right\rvert}=  \left\lvert x \right\rvert\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} \le 1$$

Comment: @TonyStarck Notice I specified $x\gt 0$, so the absolute value is not needed.